# Powershell: Download or Save source code for whole ie page

Tags: html, internet-explorer, powershell, form-submit, powershell-3.0

I have this PS script it logins to a site and then it navigate's to another page.

I want to save whole source for that page. but for some reason. some parts of source code is not coming across.

```
$username = "myuser" 
$password = "mypass"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("http://www.example.com/login.shtml")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value = "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("pass").value = "$password"
$ie.document.getElementById("frmLogin").submit()
start-sleep 5
$ie.navigate("http://www.example.com/thislink.shtml")
$ie.Document.body.outerHTML | Out-File -FilePath c:\sourcecode.txt
```

Here is pastebin of code which is not coming across
http://pastebin.com/Kcnht6Ry

Comment: The paste appears to be private.

Comment: Sorry,fixed now check it please. I did more study on it. it is ignoring code after `//<![CDATA[`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you navigate, check for the Ready State again instead of using a sleep. The same code that you had will work.

It appears after running the code, the sleep may not be long enough if the site is slow to load.

```
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
```

It also looks like there is another post regarding this
[innerHTML converts CDATA to comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065615/innerhtml-converts-cdata-to-comments) It looks like some one created a function on that page where you can clean it up. It would be something like this once you have the function declared in your code

```
htmlWithCDATASectionsToHtmlWithout($ie.Document.body.outerHTML) | Out-File -FilePath c:\sourcecode.txt
```

Comment: sorry but page loads and everything. I have visible on. problem is it is ignoring codes after `//<![CDATA[`

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I am still having getting error by using the function you posted. `At C:\Users\mmmm\Desktop\new.ps1:4 char:5
+     var ATTRS = "(?:[^>\"\]|\"[^\"]*\"|\'[^\']*\')*",`

Comment: Marking as solved, but still need to work on fixing error from that code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tkrn regarding using the while loop to wait for IE document to be ready. And for that I recommend to use at least 2 seconds inside the loop.

```
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -s 2}
```

Still I found an easier way to get the whole HTML source page exactly from the URL. Here it is:

```
$ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript("var JSIEVariable = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);", "javascript")
$obj = $ie.Document.parentWindow.GetType().InvokeMember("JSIEVariable", 4096, $null, $ie.Document.parentWindow, $null)
$HTMLDoc = $obj.ToString()
```

Now, $HTMLDoc has the whole HTML source page intact and you can save it as html file.

Comment: Do you have any explanation for that "JSIEVariable" stuff? It works but I want to know why since I don't understand at all what's happening here.